# Count the number of pairs (arr[i], arr[j]) such that arr[i] <= arr[j] and i < j

Tags: python, merge, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I'm trying to compute the number of pairs (arr[i], arr[j]) such that arr[i] <= arr[j] and i < j.

This is like a variaton of the Count Inversions problem.

I'm trying to use the same logic, using Merge Sort while counting the pairs but for some reason it is not working, I'm stuck concerning the counting pairs part.

I've already solved using an AVL Tree, but I'm trying using the Divide and Coquer Method.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance

```
def merge_count(A, B):
    res = []
    pairs = 0
    i, j = 0, 0
    
    while i < len(A) and j < len(B):
        
        if A[i] <= B[j]:
            pairs += (j-i)+1
            res.append(A[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            res.append(B[j])
            j += 1
    
    while i < len(A):
        res.append(A[i])
        i += 1
        
    while j < len(B):
        res.append(B[j])
        j += 1
        
    return pairs, res

def sort_count(nums):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        return 0, nums
    else:
        mid = (len(nums)) // 2
        L = nums[:mid]
        R = nums[mid:]
        
        pL, nL = sort_count(L)
        pR, nR = sort_count(R)
        p, nums_aux = merge_count(nL, nR)
    
        return pL+pR+p, nums_aux
```

Comment: Would `sum(1 for i,j in zip(L, L[1:]) if i <= j)` be a solution where `L` is the list?

Comment: @ChrisCharley.  The problem is all pairs, not just adjacent pairs.